# Channel Replacement Using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am currently working on a tool where 1 image's channels are needing to be replaced with 3 other images.

for example:

```
I have an image "X" and the channels would be X.r, X.g and X.b respectively.
I have 3 other images ["A","B","C"]
Those 3 images needs to replace the channels in X.

So the result would be X.A, X.B and X.C.
```

What is the best possible way to do so?

Comment: best possible way is to read documentation for [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: If you're replacing all the channels of `X`, why do you need `X` in the first place?  There wouldn't be anything left of it in the output.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC i did do some research, but nothing showed up. Hence the question. i am not looking for free codes here. way to welcome a new stackoverflow member :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [split()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split) and [merge()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.merge) and other methods

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('images/image.jpg')

r,g,b = img.split()

#r = img.getchannel(0)
#g = img.getchannel(1)
#b = img.getchannel(2)

img = Image.merge('RGB', (r,g,b))

img.show()
```

You can also convert to numpy array and work with array

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('images/image.jpg')

arr = np.array(img)

r = arr[:,:,0]
g = arr[:,:,1]
b = arr[:,:,2]

arr[:,:,0] = r
arr[:,:,1] = g
arr[:,:,2] = b

img = Image.fromarray(arr)

img.show()
```

---

Example

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open('winter.jpg')
img2 = Image.open('spring.jpg')

r1,g1,b1 = img1.split()
r2,g2,b2 = img2.split()

new_img = Image.merge('RGB', (r1,g2,b2))

new_img.show()

new_img.save('output.jpg')
```

winter.jpg

[image]

spring.jpg

[image]

output.jpg

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help. this was borderline what i was after. I wanted to merge integrate 2nd, 3rd and 4th image as RGB channels for the first one. it def did send me the right way.

i ended up changing the RGBs into grayscale mode or else it wasn't letting me copy the images into the RGB channels. so Thank you very much :)